How to do Zodios validation on a controller not inside a Zodios Router
I have set up a project to use zodios with express and react using pnpm workspaces
my folder structure is
-frontend
-common
-backend
In the common package an API definition for the user routes can be found
import z from "zod";
import { makeEndpoint, makeErrors, makeApi } from "@zodios/core";
import { User } from "@common/types/user";

const getUserErrors = makeErrors([
  {
    status: 401,
    description: "Unauthorized",
    schema: z.object({
      message: z.string(),
    }),
  },
]);

export const getUser = makeEndpoint({
  method: "get",
  path: "/user",
  response: z.object({
    user: User,
  }),
  alias: "getUser",
  description: "Get user",
  errors: getUserErrors,
});

export const userApi = makeApi([getUser]);

Then in my backend package I have routes folder with a user router file in this format
import { zodiosRouter } from '@zodios/express';
import { userApi } from '@common/api/user';
import userController from '@backend/controllers/api/v1/userController';

const userRouter = zodiosRouter(userApi);

userRouter.get('/user', userController.getUser);

There is type safety on the router itself so If I was to modify the getUser function of the userController it would be highlighted but I would also like this to be on the controller functions too
import { Request, Response, RequestHandler } from 'express';

const getUser = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.json({ user: req.session.user });
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
};

export default { getUser };

There is no mention in the documentation about this or a module named zodiosRequest, zodiosResponse etc which would satisfy my needs. Is there a workaround using Zod and Typescript so that I can achieve the level of code splitting I require
